# How to use perftools under windows

Tags: c++, windows, google-perftools

From the Readme.txt in the source, I know that it has not been tested under windows system.

Does anyone know how to make it work anyway?

Comment: Please clarify what is your problem because in version 1.8 there is README-windows in the archive which explains the steps needed.